# Restart program and random questions from Jbutton

Tags: java, swing

I have a a GUI which will display five randomly chosen questions.  The question limitation is restricted by the number of times the next question button is pressed.  When the user has finished with the five questions, I want them to press the start new round button which should restart the program.
I've never done anything like this before, and the code that I've looked at I don't understand how it works.

Here's my code:  Everything works here, I just need to add the restart button/code

```
int nextQuestionClicked;//For number of times next question is clicked

//Method to generate random questions
private String setQuestions(){
   int match = (int) Math.floor(Math.random()*cities.size());
   String whatCity = cities.get(match);
   String displayCity = "Where is " + whatCity + " located?";
   return displayCity;
   }

//What happens when next question is pressed
private void displayQuestionActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
   boolean trueOrFalse;

   submitButton.setEnabled(true);

   displayQuestion.setEnabled(false);

   outputTextQuestion.setText(null);
   outputTextQuestion.setText(setQuestions());
   outputAnswers.setText(null);        
   inputAnswer.setText(null);       
   outputDegree.setText(null);

   nextQuestionClicked++;

   int buttonLimit = 4;

   if (nextQuestionClicked  <= buttonLimit) 
   {

       int correctAnswer = -1;

        for (int x = 0; x < cities.size(); x++)
        {
            if (trueOrFalse = outputTextQuestion.getText().contains(cities.get(x)))
            {
                correctAnswer = x;
                break;
            }
        }
        randomAnswers = new ArrayList <Integer>();
        Collections.addAll(randomAnswers, correctAnswer);

        for (int x=0; x < 3; x++)
        {
           int r = correctAnswer;
           while (randomAnswers.contains(r))
            {
                r = ((int)(Math.random()*100))%cities.size();

            }
            Collections.addAll(randomAnswers, r);
        }

        Collections.shuffle(randomAnswers);
        outputAnswers.setText(null);

        for (int r=0; r<randomAnswers.size(); r++) 
        {
             int hint = randomAnswers.get(r);
             outputAnswers.append(provinces.get(hint) + "\n");
        }

        inputAnswer.requestFocus();
}

   else{
        displayQuestion.setEnabled(false);
        submitButton.setEnabled(false);
        newRound.setEnabled(true);
        outputTextQuestion.setText("Start New Round!!");
        outputDegree.setText(null);
        }
}  

private void newRoundActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    outputTextQuestion.setText(null);
    displayQuestion.setEnabled(true);
    submitButton.setEnabled(false);
//What code do I do here to restart the program?
}
```

Please help!

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: So you're asking us to write code for you? This is not a coding service...

Comment: *"the code that I've looked at I don't understand how it works"* Which gives the reader the impression you won't understand any code we offer either. So why would anyone bother trying to help? Link to the examples you saw, explain what you don't understand. Try something, and get back to us when you're stuck and have an actual question (and make it specific). General advice: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/) of your attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
private void newRoundActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
  nextQuestionClicked = 0;
  displayQuestionActionPerformed(evt);
}
```

You could add some other code instead of `displayQuestionActionPerformed()` if you want to show something other instead of the first question...

Comment: Thank you so much!!